# Unity3d and Sockets.IO won't handshake

Tags: javascript, node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io, unityscript

I am using https://github.com/kaistseo/UnitySocketIO-WebSocketSharp to enable Unity3D to talk to a Node.JS Socket.IO server.  However,  it errors out during the handshake with

*socket Error: Error initializing handshake with server*

Client code:

```
    SocketIOClient.Client socket;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    socket = new SocketIOClient.Client("http://server:80/");
    socket.On("connect", (fn) => {
        Debug.Log ("connect - socket");

        Dictionary<string, string> args = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        args.Add("msg", "what's up?");
        socket.Emit("SEND", args);
    });
    socket.On("RECV", (data) => {
        Debug.Log (data.Json.ToJsonString());
    });
    socket.Error += (sender, e) => {
        Debug.Log ("socket Error: " + e.Message.ToString ());
    };
    socket.Connect();
}
```

On the server side,

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io');

serv = app.listen(port);                                        
var sio = io.listen(serv);
sio.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('a user connected');
});
```

The server side code works fine if I connect to it with a Javascript sockets.io client.  Anyone have luck using this to connect to a sockets.io server?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using socket.io 1.0 (released May 28), try switching to 0.9.x. The linked repo was last updated on the 11th of april. 1.0 has substantial changes under the hood so the client libraries are probably not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RikkusRukkus:  If you're using socket.io 1.0 (released May 28), try switching to 0.9.x. The linked repo was last updated on the 11th of april. 1.0 has substantial changes under the hood so the client libraries are probably not interchangeable.